# Proving cosine is valid kernel

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Let $K(x,y) = \frac{x^Ty}{||x||y||}$

$K(x,y) = \frac{||x||||y||cos(\theta)}{||x||||y||} = cos(\theta)$

If we form a gram matrix $\textbf{K}$ where each $i,j$ entry is $k(a_i,b_j)$, where $a_i,b_j$ are the $i,jth$ vectors.

$\textbf{K}$ is symmetric. But how do you show that it is positive semidefinite?

In other words, how do you show how cosine kernel is, in fact, a kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that an $n\times n$ gram $\textbf{K}$ matrix whose $(i,j)$'th entry is given by $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle$ can be written as $A^tA$ where $A$ is an $n\times $n matrix whose $k$'th column is the vector $u_k$, and $k=1,2,\dots n$. It follows that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$\langle\textbf{K}x,x\rangle=\langle A^tAx,x\rangle=||Ax||^2\geq 0$$

whence $\textbf{K}$ is positive semi-definite.

In your case take $u_i=a_i/||a_i||$.

Comment: This answer didn't help me much because I've never seen a proof like this. What I want to show is for all $z^TKz \geq 0$, where $z$ is a vector in appropriate dimension.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $z^TKz$ and $\langle K z,z\rangle$ are exactly the same?

Comment: Let me trying a different example. Let the gram matrix $\textbf{K}$ be 1x1. {K(x,y) = cos($\theta$), where $\theta$ = 150 degrees. K is not positive semi-definite. So the cos kernel is not a valid kernel. Now, my question is what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. Indeed, $\cos\theta$ is not a positive function. The result holds for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. If we restrict a kernel to being positive definite, how do you show that $||Ax||^2 > 0$?